# Overwrite variables from compiled Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, label, overwrite

I'm a beginner, so the question may certainly seem simple. I'm trying to implemet a widget to my WIX-Website (https://booking-engine.camping.care/demo-cc-book-form.html). This is really easy and works perfectly well like that:

```
  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/campingcare-static/js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://booking-engine.camping.care/cc-book-form.js"></script>
  <script>
  
      const cc_settings = {
          arrival : moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          departure : moment(moment().add(1,'days')).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          accommodation_id : 0,
          public_key : '',
          language : 'de',
          admin_id : ,
          hide_search_form: true,
          hide_reservation_details: true,
          style_url: 'stylesheet-booking.css',
          birth_tables : [
              {
                  birthdate: "1978-08-02", 
                  count:1
              }, 
              {
                  birthdate: "1977-03-07", 
                  count:1
              }
          ]
      }
  </script>
  
  <cc-book-form></cc-book-form>
```

Now I would like to make some custom changes in the https://booking-engine.camping.care/cc-book-form.js File. Unfortunately if I'm copying this JavaScript-File and implement it directly in Wix, there is a Cross-Origin Error appearing.

Therfore I would like to work with the original-File from https://booking-engine.camping.care/cc-book-form.js. But is it possible to overwrite some values just in the HTML-File? Like the names of the labels in the form? There Filing them with a JSON-String:

```
    /***/ "0a64":
    /***/ (function(module) {
    
    module.exports = JSON.parse("{\"Please check all the req...
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change some visual stuff you could try using `document.querySelector("#YOUR_ID").innerHTML = "Whatever you want";`

(I hope this is what you need and I didn't understand your question wrong)
You could also take a look here for more information:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp